# Historical german rain radar data from opendata.dwd.de

Tags: data-request, weather

Recently the German national weather service (DWD) published lots of data. I am especially interested in the 5 minutes radar data stored at:

https://opendata.dwd.de/weather/radar/composit/wx/ or 
https://opendata.dwd.de/weather/radar/composit/pg/

However, this folder only contains the data for the last 2 days. Does anyone knows how to get older versions of that data? There is older data on the server but only with hourly data, but I need it in 5 (or 10) minutes resolution.

Comment: Did you browse up through the directory tree to see if there's anything in another branch?

Comment: Yes. There is some stuff in https://opendata.dwd.de/climate linking to ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/daily/radolan/ but only in 1 hour resultion not in 5-10 minutes as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [old question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11610/looking-for-precipitation-scans-radar-for-germany-5-min-intervals-1-a) I posted a while ago ...

The short answer is, if you want this data for longer periods of time (i.e. > 48 hrs), you have to get in touch with DWD. They will retrieve it for you from their archives ... for a fee. After I got this information, I set up an hourly cron job for the [first of your links](https://opendata.dwd.de/weather/radar/composit/wx/), because I was simply interested in having such data for a longer (yet not specific) period of time:

```
#!/bin/bash

su -c "lftp -c \"set ftp:list-options -a;
open ftp://opendata.dwd.de;
lcd /path/to/some/storage/DWD/wx_composit;
cd /weather/radar/composit/wx;
mirror --use-cache --verbose --allow-chown --allow-suid --no-umask --parallel=4\"" someusername
```

My "personal archive" reaches back to noon (UTC) 2017-08-05 (39k files, 36 GByte) ;)

Comment: Did you check e.g. the mentioned [radolan directory](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/hourly/radolan/historical/asc/) on the DWD Data Server ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC? There is historical data available up to 2005.